# How are let bindings represented with lambda expressions?

Tags: haskell, lambda

In a normal Haskell do block, I can specify values to be evaluated to a let binding, though I'm not quite sure how that translates to a lambda expression.

Taking the following (small) example

```hs
letEx :: IO [Char]
letEx = do
  let x = [v | v <- [1 .. 100], v `mod` 2 == 0]
  return $ show x
```

Would be represented with something similar to this

```hs
lambdaEx :: [Char]
lambdaEx = ([v | v <- [1 .. 100], v `mod` 2 == 0]) >>= \x -> show x
```

I cannot personally figure out how it properly is represented. Let expressions seem helpful, but their non `do` notation representation is a bit confusing.

Comment: "I can specify values to be evaluated to a let binding, though I'm not quite sure how that translates to a lambda expression" -- it doesn't. `let` is an additional concept, different from lambdas. In particular: `let`-bound variables can be polymorphic, while lambda-bound variables cannot. (The lambda itself may be polymorphic, but the variable it binds is not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, this is a [`let … in …` expression <sup>[Haskell-wiki]</sup>](https://wiki.haskell.org/Let_vs._Where), so:

```
lambdaEx :: IO [Char]
lambdaEx = let x = [v | v <- [1 .. 100], v `mod` 2 == 0] in return (show x)
```

but here it makes not much sense to use a `let` anyway, this is just:

```
lambdaEx :: IO [Char]
lambdaEx = return (show [v | v <- [1 .. 100], v `mod` 2 == 0])
```

As you probably know already, you can remove the modulo two check in this case with:

```
lambdaEx :: IO [Char]
lambdaEx = return (show [2, 4 .. 100])
```